Performing spatial regressions with huge datasets without crashing the computer
I'm running a spatial regression (SAR: spatial autoregressive regression) in R using the spmodel package. My dataset is a sf object formed by centroids.
This dataset has 100'781 observations, and I created a list of 3 neighborhoods for each observation.
With this information, I run the following code:
library( "spmodel" )

Model_splm <- splm( formula       =  variables, 
                    data          =  subset, 
                    listw         =  NbList, 
                    model         = "pooling",
                    lag           =  T,
                    spatial.error = "b",
                    parallel      =  T,
                    local         =  list( parallel = T )
                    ) 

As you can see, I'm using parallel processing to speed up the performance of this regression (my computer has 8 cores and 16 logical processors). However, I'm not able to perform this code because my computer crashes. I'm only able to run this regression when the number of observations is ~ 40'000.
Does anyone have a suggestion of how to be able to perform that regression in my computer? Or any other suggestions? This was just an example, but I need to run multiple spatial regressions, and I've been struggling with this.

"because my computer crashes" It is hard know exactly why without more information but I guess this is because it does not have enough memory for the computation. Note that swap memory can help to push this limit further though is is slow (a slow program is better than one crashing ;) ). This assume you have enough storage space and possibly a Nvme SSD (HDD and SATA-SSD are really too slow for that). With this solution, using multiple is certainly useless since the swap will be the bottleneck.

AFAIK, In R, parallelism is generally achieved using multiple processes (and inter-process communication -- a.k.a. IPC) simply because AFAIK the interpreter does not really support multi-threading (directly for the interpreted code, like CPython). The thing is this way of writing parallel program tends to require significantly more memory. The only solution is to use a native module creating threads internally. Native module tends to also consume less memory since R tends to create a lot of copies taking a lot more memory than actually required.

On you side, maybe you can adapt the number of process and check if this is better (using a basic task manager, like htop on Linux).

Thanks for your answer, @JérômeRichard. Do you have by any chance an example of how to perform this with the regression I'm trying to do? Sorry for the question but I'm completely ignorant on how to do this.

So as to prevent any (almost) clairvoyance kinds of pseudo-wisdoms, could you kindly specify all missing facts? (a) WHAT operating system your R-code runs on { Windows, macOS, Linux, AIX, ... }? (b) WHAT is your computing device RAM-size [GB]? (c) WHAT is your actual computing device type { DataCenter HPC, Desktop PC, Laptop PC, virtual machine like Docker or similar VM-host in some Cloud(y) ecosystem, ... }? (d) What are common day-time temperatures in August in locations, where you run the crashing code ( 've seen many systems crash in hot, humid summers in real world )

Sure, here is the information:


Q1 :" Or any other suggestions? "

Well, the spmodel authors' paper is brutally open on computational complexity being rather prohibitive in naive use on un-curated data - explicitly warningabout explodinginto exponential EXP-[ TIME?, SPACE? ] and cubic or quadratic POLYNOMIAL-[ TIME?, SPACE? ] limits the use of this package runs into :

The computational cost associated with model fitting is exponential in the sample size for all estimation methods. For maximum likelihood and restricted maximum likelihood, the computational cost of estimating θ is cubic. For semivariogram weighted least squares and semivariogram composite likelihood, the computational cost of estimating θ is quadratic. The computational cost associated with estimating β and prediction is cubic in the model-fitting sample size, regardless of estimation method. Typically, samples sizes approaching 10,000 make the computational cost of model fitting and prediction infeasible, which necessitates the use of big data methods. spmodel offers big data methods for model fitting of point-referenced data via the local argument to splm(). The method is capable of quickly fitting models with hundreds of thousands to millions of observations. Because of the neighborhood structure of areal data, the big data methods used for point-referenced data do not apply to areal data. Thus, there is no big data method for areal data or local argument to spautor(), so model fitting sample sizes cannot be too large. spmodel offers big data methods for prediction of point-referenced data or areal data via the local argument to predict(), capable of quickly predicting hundreds of thousands to millions of observations rather quickly.

Rather clear & sound, isn't it?


Q2 :" Does anyone have a suggestion of how to be able to perform that regression in my computer? "

Besides a few tricks to eliminate the EXP-[ TIME?, SPACE? ] by pre-clustering and alikes, already offered in the paper, you can try to use and benefit from modern hypervisor-coordinated ultra-scaled computing fabrics, like Dr. Isaac R. Nassi's invented reverse-hypervised computing infrastructure, that ( in spite of all the technology in the background ) still seems for your operating system and the R-code as if it were a single "immensely-large" PC, with almost infinite RAM scales, operating almost infinite CPU-cores, coordinated by Ike's genial reversed-hypervisor ( patented technology recently acquired by ( really ) Big Data ( not just a few hundreds thousands points ) big vendor, so should be available for academic or similar efforts to run a PoC on their premises ).
Making the same with an ordinary computer seems a priori not possible, as authors warned.

Many thanks, @user3666197. I'll keep this information in mind. Sorry for my ignorance, but is this related to the memory thing that Jérôme Richard mentioned in his answer?
